# Import react-mdl

Tags: reactjs, webpack, browserify

Please help, I trying to import react-mdl to my project

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-mdl/lib/Icon';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Icon name="add" />
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

I get an error, I can not understand why
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E9m5.png)

How fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Install `react-mdl` by using:

`npm install --save react-mdl`

Use this to import `Icon`:

```
import { Icon } from 'react-mdl';
```